# SDL2_image.dll cannot be found

Tags: visual-studio, sdl

After adding the SDL_image library to my project I tried running a program but got the Systemerror that the SDL2_image.dll cannot be found.I added the SDL_image files to my SDL2 folder and added SDL2_image.lib to my dependencies. Also I included the SDL_image.h.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Runtime linker searches DLLs in executable's dir and [some other places](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx), put it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recognized I forgot to copy the .dll File to my project folder.